# How to run Google Chrome as a background process?

Tags: google-chrome, background-process

I'd like to run Google Chrome as a background app on my Linux install the way it does in Windows.  There are some things I use that don't have good Linux ports but the Chrome extension works wonderfully on (in particular the functionality of pushbullet).

However, I've tried everything I can find, but it still never runs in the background.  And help would be appreciated.

When I run the command in the console, I get these errors:

```
[14711:14711:0312/175429:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(325)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[14676:14708:0312/175431:ERROR:channel.cc(305)] RawChannel read error (connection broken) 
[14676:14708:0312/175431:ERROR:channel.cc(305)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[14676:14708:0312/175431:ERROR:channel.cc(305)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[14676:14708:0312/175431:ERROR:channel.cc(305)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
```

Comment: Did you try `google-chrome --no-startup-window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While on Windows any extension that can run in the background will also trigger the background Chrome to run.  On Linux the background Chrome seems to only stay in memory if an extension expressly requests a background presence.  This occurs even when you specify the *--no-startup-window command* line switch.

If you specify the switch and an extension which requests a background presence is not installed, Chrome loads and then exits as there is no window open.  This behavior can be solved by adding an extension to Chrome that specifically requests to be run in the background.  The Hangouts extension is a good example of this.

I do not personally run the Hangouts extension, but I found a little, unobtrusive [timer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/countdown/fefdcjabloofphhfcinh%20fbinmehfcojm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) that fills the need to have an extension specifically request to run in the background, called countDown.

Answer (score 0):

Open Startup Applications, and create a new entry with this for the command:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window
```

Comment: I tried that, it did not work.  Chrome starts, but then it exits.  No processes for Chrome remain in memory.  Even if I run that manually (either Terminal or via Alt-F2), still no effect.

Comment: I added my errors from the console, if that will help.